# Query String isn't showing all value

Tags: php, query-string

Trying to send a absolute path through query string:

```
$abs_path=realpath(__DIR__);
```

This is the string while echoing:

```
D:\Working Projects\wamp\www\gbl_admin\filemanager/uploads
```

This is the actual query string I am getting:

```
http://localhost/gbl_admin/filemanager/dir_mgmt.php?action=new_dir&&location=D:\Working Projects\wamp\
```

I even tried replacing space with %20:

```
$abs_path=str_replace(" ","%20",$abs_path);
```

By how much i know i think i haven't crossed the query limit. How can i solve this?

This is the  tag inside a Heredoc Syntax:

```
<a href=$dir_mgmt?action=new_dir&&location=$abs_path>New Folder</a>
```

and

```
$dir_mgmt="http://localhost/gbl_admin/filemanager/dir_mgmt.php";
```

Comment: You have two `&&` in the query string.

Comment: it's allowed i think even though le me try

Comment: still the same result

Comment: You have to use [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: do i have to use urldecode() while getting it ?